# having trouble with scan a string in an infinity loop in c

Tags: c

I wanna get an input text reading from  file, then calculate the word with the maximum length and finally print the number of words with maximum length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buf[1000];
    ptr_file =fopen("text.txt","r");
    while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
        printf("%s",buf);
    fclose(ptr_file);
    int MaxLength = 0, i = 0, counter;
    while(scanf("%s", buf) != -1)
    {
    if (strlen(buf) > MaxLength)
    {
        MaxLength = strlen(buf);
        counter = 0;
    }
    if (strlen(buf) == MaxLength)
        counter++;
    }
    printf("%d", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: file reopen then `while(scanf("%s",` --> `while(fscanf(ptr_file, "%s",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buf[1000];
    ptr_file =fopen("text.txt","r");
    while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
        printf("%s",buf);
    fclose(ptr_file);
    int MaxLength = 0, i = 0, counter;
    ptr_file =fopen("text.txt","r");
    while(fscanf(ptr_file, "%s", buf) != -1)
    {
        if (strlen(buf) > MaxLength)
        {
            MaxLength = strlen(buf);
            counter = 0;
        }
        if (strlen(buf) == MaxLength)
            counter++;
    }
    printf("%d", counter);
    fclose(ptr_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
./a.out
foo
bar
baz
foobaz
bletch
2
```